# Does Apple's Disk Utility 'Restore' function make a 'byte for byte' clone?

Tags: mac, disk-utility, mojave, data-recovery

I've used Apple's Disk Utility to 'restore' a drive with accidentally deleted files.  I need to know if this is an exact byte-for-byte clone that I can scan for deleted files on.

Comment: What is the format of the volume with deleted files? Is the drive internal or external?

Comment: @DavidAnderson APFS. It was an internal system drive that has been restored to an external HDD for file recovery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a "byte-for-byte" clone. The only exception is if the source volume is defective and contains read-errors. In that case you would be better off using a specialised copying program, such as ddrescue.